# How to install gtest

Tags: ros, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the ros gtest wiki page (http://wiki.ros.org/gtest):

```
In ROS 1.0 (Box Turtle) and 1.2 (C Turtle), gtest is included as a ROS package. In later releases of ROS, it has been converted to a rosdep.
```

However, when I run the command:

```
$ rosdep install gtest
```

I get:

```
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource gtest
```

The same thing happens if I run the command as root and with I all the variants I can think of (including g-test, googletest, and google-test). So how does one install gtest?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114121/how-to-install-gtest/) by [astrokenny](https://answers.ros.org/users/4041/astrokenny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2013-12-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosdep takes ROS packages as arguments and installs their dependencies.

If you want to install gtest on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtest-dev
```

I got the above native package name by using

```
rosdep resolve gtest
```

If you have a package, foo_package, with a dependency on gtest you can say:

```
rosdep install foo_package
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-12-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0